# How to reference *just* the image part of an image node in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm building a recipe management system for a cooking website in Drupal, and I have to say the whole node / view / template thing is working very nicely! I've got one problem though and that is that I can't get a view to display *JUST* an image - it always comes bundled with it's title and a link through to the gallery.

Can anyone help me work out how to reference an image from a view, only displaying the image itself with no linkage or anything else?

Setup

- Image installed
- Content type "recipe" created
- CCK Image field used to bring image into "recipe"
- View created - has the right image field referenced

Can select "body" or teaser on the view options for the image field, but neither is correct really. I thought about trying to re-write the output of that field, but there is no way of just passing along the file path it seems.

H

Comment: Your setup is a bit confusing, as it lists both CCK ImageField and the Image Module. These two provide different ways to use images in Drupal and *do not work together*. In addition, you mention a 'link through to the gallery'. What gallery is this (this might give a hint on what image your view is using).

Comment: ah sorry, I meant the image node itself - the full node with all the details about the image. It's interesting that CCK and Module don't work together - shall have to look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the *node* row style. If you set the row style to *fields*, you should be able to just display the image field.

Comment: That was it! Just had to change the field I was trying to use from a node-reference to an actual CCK image field. Then when the image was uploaded via the content creation form, I could reference just the image from within the views set up. Drupal really isn't simple sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/ImageCache) for all image manipulations. Then you get a lot of options when you edit the Display Fields of your node type, e.g.

- Image display with link to node
- Image display with no link
- Thumbnail display with link to original picture
- Thumbnail display with no link

etc etc. Very useful, but it might confuse things further to have another image-based module doing things!

Comment: TBH I'm not overley impressed with Drupals base ability to handle files or images. It requires a great deal of configuration of PHP knowledge to get it right. Sounds like Drupal 7 is addressing this though, will be interesting to see!